# What do letters "R" and "E" before parking slots in Spain mean?

Tags: spain, automobiles, factoids, terminology, basque-country

In Spain, more precisely in the Basque Country, I have seen letters "R" and "E" before parking slots.

What do they mean / stand for?

[image: R E R E R]
This one is in the [town of Zumaia](https://www.google.com/maps/@43.2979231,-2.2603789,3a,60y,116.26h,79.28t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sw6JW8lpytAxHjDPE8lbkvQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).
*Picture is taken on Google Street View.*

Comment: Perhaps the exact location might give a clue?

Comment: @Berwyn Added..

Comment: My guess is Estacionamiento Residentes, but it's purely a guess

Comment: my guess is the direction that the car should park...

Comment: @MarcelP. this was my first guess, but the same letters show up in places where there's parking spaces on both sides of the road, as well as where parking spaces are perpendicular to the road, so that doesn't quite fit.

Comment: @jcaron I can only assume that Marcel was joking, based on the fact that the first three cars alternate in direction in the photograph. It would be ludicrous for the city council to require cars parked at the kerb to be parked in alternating directions: the only sane options are "park whichever way you want" and "park facing the same way as the traffic."

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The road on the photo appears to be wider, but for narrower (one driving lane + one parking lane in total) roads with two-way traffic, "the traffic" can indeed go both ways.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sure but it would still be ludicrous to reserve alternating parking spaces for cars facing in each direction.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [Zumaia website](https://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=https://zumaia.eus/es/noticias/manana-entrara-en-vigor-el-sistema-de-regulacion-del-aparcamiento&prev=search):

> There will be 3 parking areas:
>
> - **Resident area (painted white with the letters R and E)**
> - Areas of high rotation (A, B and C: painted blue and red)
> - Half-stay area (painted blue)

(Google translation, emphasis mine).

Note that this seems to be in use in some other places. Other cities make extensive use of blue-and-red, blue-and-green and whatnot.

Just to complete the consequences of those innocent letters:

> **Resident area:**
>
> Only people with a resident card can park here.

Comment: So is there any difference between the E and the R spots?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann it seems to be just an easy scheme to alternate the letters at a decent distance from one another...

Comment: I for one would like to know what the E stands for. Certainly the R is for  *residente(s)*, but I can’t figure out what the E is for. It’s certainly not for *zona*. The only "e"-word that jumps out in the article is *estancia*, but that doesn’t seem to connect up with the residential part.

Comment: Perhaps E is for the second letter of "residente"? The way they alternate they seem to abbreviate the word...

Comment: As suggested by [@Berwyn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112045/what-do-letters-r-and-e-before-parking-slots-in-spain-mean#comment273047_112045) it’s probably Estacionamiento Residentes

Comment: @jcaron Yes, the "e" stands for *estacionamiento*. So E (estacionamiento) R (residentes).

Comment: *"Other cities make extensive use of blue-and-red, blue-and-green..."* This brings to mind a basic concept I learned about Web accessibility: *don't convey important information using color alone as many people are color-blind.*

Comment: If you look at the [Basque version of the page](https://zumaia.eus/eu/albisteak/bihar-jarriko-da-martxan-aparkamendua-antolatzeko-sistema?set_language=eu), the Resident's card is referred to as "Egoiliar Txartela", so maybe the "E" is for "Egoiliar" (later spelled as "Egoilar").

Comment: Please note that the white zone is for loading and unloading passengers only. There is no parking in the red zone.

Comment: I'll vote for "egoiliar"/"egoilar" too (Google translate suggests one might be an adjective "resident" and the other a noun "resident", for what that's worth).